How to use ASP.NET Core identity mongodbcore, and what methods does it support?
I'm new to mongo DB, I can perform basic crud operations in mongo, but now want to learn about identity management in mongo db, there are two packages regarding identity

aspnetcore.identity.mongodb
aspnetcore.identity.mongodbcore

What are the differences between them? It's difficult to find out.
I want to manage user identity in mongo as it is done in SQL Server with Entity Framework Core and MS identity.

It is recommended to use AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDBCore, as described in github, which has been verified with 737 integration tests and unit tests to ensure compatibility with the native Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.Test test suite.
Comparison of downloads and last update time.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB#versions-body-tab

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore/#versions-body-tab

Conclusion
Judging from the download volume and maintenance time of Nuget, AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDBCore has more advantages. The more people use it, the more stable it is, and we will get more community support when we encounter problems.

Analysis from the code level
AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore is encapsulated at a more basic level, which means that customized functions can be performed according to needs.
Example：
MongoIdentityUser （AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore）
Implemented IDocument and IClaimHolder interfaces, additional attributes such as Claims, Roles, Logins, Tokens, etc. are added to manage user details. These attributes make this class more extensible and flexible.
vs
MongoUser (AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDb)
It inherits directly from the IdentityUser<TKey> class and implements no additional interfaces. This means that it relies more on the standard implementation of the ASP.NET Core Identity framework.
Use standard types such as IdentityUserClaim<string>, IdentityUserLogin<string>, and IdentityUserToken<string> are used instead of custom types like in the AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore library. This makes it more suitable for simple user management needs.
